# Chess Engine with Python-Based / API?

Tags: engines, python

I went through the most popular chess engines, e.g. StockFish, Komodo, Rykba and so forth, but I wasn't able to a.) find an API or b.) a python based Engine - does anyone know a suitable project?

I want to implement a chess engine in a python-based gameportal I'm building (offering to analyse the game after the chess round), though it's an assigned project and I need to use purely Python (except graphics) for the project, hence I was either looking for a proper API or Python based Chess Engine - anyone knows an implementation?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a chess engine in Python: [Sunfish](https://github.com/thomasahle/sunfish)

There is also a python library for chess: [python-chess](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/)